# Jquery tablesorter - Include all child rows when selecting a parent row

Tags: jquery, each, tablesorter

This seems like an easy enough function but for some reason, I'm struggling to make it work. I have an HTML table with the jquery tablesorter plug in. Each row has a checkbox as the first column. By default, all child rows are hidden. When I select the checkbox on the parent row, I want it to also mark the checkboxes on the child rows under that parent as selected. Here is my HTML table:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Select</th>
      <th>Column2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr class="tablesorter-hasChildRow">
       <td><input type="checkbox" class="rowSelector"></td>
       <td>Column 2 Data</td>
     <tr>
     <tr class="tablesorter-childRow">
       <td><input type="checkbox" class="rowSelector"></td>
       <td>Column 2 Data</td>
     <tr>
     <tr class="tablesorter-childRow">
       <td><input type="checkbox" class="rowSelector"></td>
       <td>Column 2 Data</td>
     <tr>
     <tr class="tablesorter-hasChildRow">
       <td><input type="checkbox" class="rowSelector"></td>
       <td>Column 2 Data</td>
     <tr>
     <tr class="tablesorter-childRow">
       <td><input type="checkbox" class="rowSelector"></td>
       <td>Column 2 Data</td>
     <tr>
     <tr class="tablesorter-childRow">
       <td><input type="checkbox" class="rowSelector"></td>
       <td>Column 2 Data</td>
     <tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

And here is my javascript. I get to the point where the alert works, the part I'm having a hard time with is now selecting all child rows under this parent (the number of child rows will vary from parent to parent) & then select the checkbox. In other areas, I used prop('checked') but I need it to toggle so that if the parent is UN-checked, the children will uncheck as well.

```
$(.rowSelector').change(function() {
    if ($(this).closest('tr').hasClass('tablesorter-hasChildRow')) {
        alert('Yay!');  //this part works
        $(this).nextAll('tr').each(function () {
            if ($(this).has('.tablesorter-childRow')) {
              $(this).find(input.rowSelector).toggleClass('selected');
             }
        });
   };
});
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: For one your closing `tr` tags are not actually closing. They're opening tags.

Comment: Oops! I forgot them in re-typing it. thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with the HTML... make sure to use `</tr>` when closing a row. This HTML will create two rows, the first being empty.

```
<tr>
<tr class="tablesorter-hasChildRow">
```

Anyway, I created [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/tfhnh5d4/) which does all the necessary checkbox determination that @rtytgat mentioned:

- Setting a parent will make all children have the same check state
- Child rows with a combo of checked & unchecked will make the parent indeterminate.
- If all child rows have the same state, the parent is set to that state.

```
$(function() {

  var parentClass = '.tablesorter-hasChildRow',
    rowSelector = '.rowSelector';

  // return parent + all children
  function getGroupRows($row) {
    var isParent = $row.hasClass(parentClass.slice(1)),
      $rows = $row.nextUntil(parentClass).add($row),
      $prev = $row.prevUntil(parentClass).add($row);
    return isParent ? $rows : $rows.add($prev).add($prev.prev());
  }

  $('table')
    .tablesorter({
      theme: 'blue'
    })
    .on('change', rowSelector, function() {
      var $rows, checked, len,
        isChecked = this.checked,
        $row = $(this).closest('tr'),
        $group = getGroupRows($row);
      if ($row.hasClass(parentClass.slice(1))) {
        // parent checked, now (un)check all children
        $group.find('.rowSelector').prop('checked', isChecked);
      } else {
        // child row (un)checked, now figure out what to do with the parent
        $rows = $group.filter('.tablesorter-childRow');
        checked = $rows.find(rowSelector + ':checked').length;
        len = isChecked ? checked : $rows.length - checked;
        if (len === $rows.length) {
          // all child rows are the same, set the parent to match
          $group.filter(parentClass).find(rowSelector).prop({
            indeterminate: false,
            checked: isChecked
          });
        } else {
          // combo of checked & unchecked, make parent indeterminate
          $group.filter(parentClass).find(rowSelector).prop({
            indeterminate: true,
            checked: false
          });
        }
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: Mottie to the rescue!! Wow, this is perfect. I feel badly changing my accepted answer because @rtytgat did answer the question I asked, but this one definitely took it a step further. I also like the addition of the parent indeterminate checkbox. This is a very user-friendly solution. Thank you so much!!

Comment: This probably should be a separate question but since you have this mastered, I figured its worth asking. Does the plugin have a function that would count the selected parent vs child rows? I have one that just counts all rows but it's messing up when I implement this. I can't seem to find a reason why it's going weird either. Is there some documentation on this you could point me to?

Comment: There isn't anything built-in. You can modify the code above to add a count if you want... Use `$group.length` to get the total row count (parent + children), or `$rows.length` for the total number of child rows.

Answer (score 1):

And here's working code:

```
$('.rowSelector').change(function() {
  $(this).closest('tr.tablesorter-hasChildRow').nextUntil('tr.tablesorter-hasChildRow').find('input.rowSelector').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

Well, sort of working. Ideally you'll still want to also toggle the higher level ticks when all the lower ones have been selected manually.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking to do! Thank you so much. I think I was making it more complicated than it needed to be. And I didn't even think about the other scenario where a parent row should be checked when all children have been selected. Thanks for not only helping me make it work, but also helping make it better!!!